# Sql Server View with Inner Joins Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to understand how Sql Server handles views and joins inside the views.

I have a view something like.

```
CREATE VIEW 
        [dbo].[vw_Product]
AS
    SELECT
        Product.Id AS ProductId,
        Customer.Name AS CustomerName
    FROM
        Product
    INNER JOIN
        Customer ON Customer.Id = Product.CustomerId
```

What is the difference between the following two queries in terms of performance?

```
SELECT ProductId, CustomerName FROM vw_Product

SELECT ProductId FROM vw_Product
```

The reason for asking this question is that the first query selects CustomerName. In the view there is an Inner Join on the Customer table. An Inner Join execution has its extra cost on the performance.

Comment: Since productID is primarykey, so it's indexed, there is no need to acces the table for the second query, just the index.

Comment: Your view must always include the INNER JOIN since it only return records where customer id exists in both tables. If you change to a LEFT JOIN there is no need to do the join for the second query so it will be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the second query will be a bit slower, because the data returned by the SQL Server contains additional column. In both cases `INNER JOIN` will take place.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter whether you select column from single table or multiple tables, the JOIN is performed always. So I would say the difference is negligible